# Using Number.isFinite() vs comparing to Infinity vs comparing to Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY to check if a number is finite

Tags: javascript, numbers, infinity

There are multiple ways to check if a number is finite.

1. Using [`Number.isFinite()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isFinite) function:

   ```
   Number.isFinite(number)
   ```
2. Comparing to [`Infinity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity):

   ```
   Math.abs(number) !== Infinity
   ```

   I'm using `Math.abs()` here in case the number is `-Infinity`.
3. Comparing to [`Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/POSITIVE_INFINITY):

   ```
   Math.abs(number) !== Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY
   ```

Are there any differences between using these three methods? I'm assuming that `Infinity` is read only, as stated in ECMAScript 5 specification.

Comment: what do you mean by read-only?!

Comment: @BekimBacaj It means that you can't assign anything to `Infinity`, for example you can't do `Infinity = 8`.

Comment: you cannot assign anything to any number, object or primitive either, why should the infinity number behave any different?
e.g.: you cannot do 8 = 2 either!

Comment: @BekimBacaj `Infinity` is a property of a global object and prior to ECMAScript 5 it was possible to assign a different value to it.

Comment: Another way to check is: `!!(1/number)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

2 and 3 are the same because `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY === Infinity`. 1 and 2 will handle `NaN` differently, see http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-number.isfinite

Comment: In short: `Number.isFinite(NaN) === false` .